# textutil producing invalid list html output

Tags: ruby, text

The utility textutil, which is an integral part of a large project I'm working on, has decided to no longer process nested lists correctly. Here is a screenshot of my Word doc (all formatted as lists, using tab to indent one more level) and the html output.

Notice in the below example that the `ul` beginning with "How are you today" should actually be *inside* the preceding `li` tag "Hi there".

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get textutil to format the lists correctly, or does anyone have a suggestion for a Ruby library that might do the same?

[image: docx input]

Current textutil output:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1">Hi there</li>
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1">How are you today</li>
    <li class="li1">I hope this works</li>
    <li class="li1">If it doesn’t</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="li1">We have a problem</li>
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1">Such problem</li>
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">So weighty</li>
      <li class="li1">Many issues</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="li1">Don’t know what to do</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</body>
```

Desired output:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1">Hi there
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">How are you today</li>
      <li class="li1">I hope this works</li>
      <li class="li1">If it doesn’t</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li1">We have a problem
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">Such problem
        <ul class="ul1">
          <li class="li1">So weighty</li>
          <li class="li1">Many issues</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="li1">Don’t know what to do</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: The HTML is wrong. The order of elements should be `ul > li`, and `ul > ul` is invalid html.

Comment: Yes...this is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. The html printed up there is the (invalid) code that textutil generates.

Comment: Is textutil a custom lib? We need to see the code in order to help you

Comment: How is a Word doc involved in this? Can you provide more information on what you're trying to do? What is the input, and what is the desired output?

Comment: textutil is a terminal program that comes with OSX. The Word doc input is the screenshot, and the output I receive is in the code block below the screenshot. As you can see, textutil generates invalid html code. I'm adding the desired output below.